# Java.lang.String cannot be converted to jsonobeject

Tags: android, json, wcf

my problem is that when i try to parse from my wcf service into android it gives me an error. the return for my service is with JSON. this is my android code:

```
  DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // http get request
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8181/Managers/Authentification.svc/authen/?loga="+t1.getText().toString()+"&pass="+t2.getText().toString());

    // set the hedear to get the data in JSON formate
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    //get the response
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    System.out.println("Connectee--->" +response.getAllHeaders());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    //if entity contect lenght 0, means no data exist in the system with these code
    if(entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
        // stream reader object
        Reader employeeReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
        //create a buffer to fill it from reader
        char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
        //fill the buffer by the help of reader
        employeeReader.read(buffer);
        //close the reader streams
        employeeReader.close();

        //for the employee json object
        JSONObject tt =  new JSONObject(new String(buffer));

        System.out.println("..................OK.........................");

        System.out.println("Reference: " + tt.getString("Reference"));



    }
    else {
        System.out.println("...................Not OK........................");
    }

}
catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println("...................ERRORJSON........................");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("...................ERROR........................");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
});
```

error message :

```
05-06 16:34:04.256: I/System.out(7257): Connectee--->[Lorg.apache.http.Header;@40d2b900
05-06 16:34:04.296: I/System.out(7257): ...................ERRORJSON........................
05-06 16:34:04.316: W/System.err(7257): org.json.JSONException: Value {"Reference":""} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Log the response from the server before you try to create the JSONObject and post it here. Apparently you're not getting valid JSON back.

Comment: And please do not post questions twice!

Comment: Reference":"","Objet":{"Login":null,"Mtspass":null,"Code_session":"616e0e76-fc5e-4df7-9079-d65cc15f1dd7"},"Status_code":"","Status_label":""}

Answer (score 2):

u have an array attribute : Reference, which has to be defined in JSONString like this:
    {"Reference":[]}
for example
{"Reference":[{"id":1,"referenceName":"name1"},{"id":2,"referenceName":"name2"}]}

Comment: no it's not like that this is the whole reponse from the server looks like:{Reference":"","Objet":{"Login":null,"Mtspass":null,"Code_session":"616e0e76-fc5e‌​-4df7-9079-d65cc15f1dd7"},"Status_code":"","Status_label":""}

Comment: do a System.out.println((new String(buffer)) and let me see the result

Comment: 05-07 15:01:51.002: I/System.out(8550): "{\"Reference\":\"test\",\"Objet\":{\"Login\":null,\"Mtspass\":null,\"Code_session\":\"6916cd6a-6a0e-4ee4-a162-2c4e2e67244f\"},\"Status_code\":\"\",\"Status_label\":\"\"}"

Comment: here is the problem, normally, it has to be like that
{"Reference":"test",...} 
it shouldn't have the backslash, I dont know where it comes from, but try to verify your web service

Comment: I found the problem, its the backslash and quotes this is my solution:   String x=new String(buffer);
      String y=x.replace("\\","");
      if (y.startsWith("\""))
           {
               y = y.substring(1, y.length());
           }
           if (y.endsWith("\""))
           {
               y = y.substring(0, y.length() - 1);
           }
      
      JSONObject reader =  new JSONObject(y);